# Thread/Timer/App isn't getting stopped when I press the Back Button on the Splash Screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

Even if I press the back button, my timer is still running and the next activity is executed after the specified time. How do I stop this?
Splash.java :

```
package com.ultimate.biggboss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;
public class Splash extends Activity{
    VideoView vid;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        vid = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
        String urlpath="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.logoanimate;
        vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlpath));
        vid.start();
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{ 
                    Intent openHome = new Intent(Splash.this, main.class);
                    startActivity(openHome);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

What code do I write and where in this class to stop the app as soon as I press the back button?

Comment: http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html. use `interrupt`

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the back key press in the following way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // your code.
}
```

and before API 5 use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // your code
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Inside this, you can do something like:

```
if(null != timer){
        timer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that the Thread's stop(), suspend() etc., methods have been
>   deprecated, the only way to safely terminate a thread is to have it
>   exit its run() method.

**Try following:**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

private long sleepTime;
private boolean stop;   

public MyThread(long sleepTime) {       
    this.sleepTime = sleepTime;
    stop = false;
}

public void run() {

    do {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while (!stop);
}

// soft stopping of thread
public synchronized void stopThread() {
    stop = true;
}
```

}

**To start the thread:**

```
MyThread timer = new MyThread(4400);
timer.start();
```

**To stop the thread:**

```
timer.stopThread();
```

So you can handle it on pressing back button like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(timer != null){
      timer.stopThread();
      timer = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should interrupt the Thread

```
 public void onBackPressed() 
{
     timer.interrupt();
     this.finish();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a flag to stop a thread, below is how i had done it:

```
public static int flag=0;//whenever flag=1, stop the thread. Flag should be a static global variable

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    flag=1;
}

//My thread code was somewhat like this:

Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                     while(1)
                     {
                         if(flag==0)
                              //My code here
                         else
                               stopThread(this);
                     }
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
```

The code for stopThread() is given below:

```
private synchronized void stopThread(Thread theThread)
{
    if (theThread != null)
    {
        theThread = null;
    }
}
```

This code worked for me. Hope it helps you too.